# Call parent class from child class PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

people.
I'm here again trying to solve a problem here .
All my code can be see here:

```
https://gitlab.com/zoiobnu/comissiosystem
```

I have a Main.py with MainWindow that have menu, toolbar . Then toolbar call Widget with form . This form have a search button (Pesquisar) that open a dialog and close widget .

ItemForm.py

```
    def search(self):
        item_search = ItemSearch(self)
        item_search.show()
        self.close()
```

[image]

Than this new search dialog i can search in DB and get ID .

ItemSearch.py

```
        @pyqtSlot()
        def on_click(self):
            item_form = ItemForm(codigo=self.grdPesquisaCliente.item(self.grdPesquisaCliente.currentRow(), 0).text())
            item_form.show()
            ItemSearch.close()
```

[image]

I can now doubleClick on row and get cell id , but i want to return to first form with this cell id and fill fields with db data .

But i don't know how to make this work .

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, You should be able to create a signal in the itemSearch that emits the row's text as a tuple when it's double-clicked. You would just need to connect the signal to a ` set_item(item)`  method in the previous form and call `setText(item[...])` on the lineEdit's in the itemForm.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem i maked this !
Created a new method on parent class to fill form , then called with self.parent()

ItemSearch.py

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    self.parent().fill_data(codigo=self.grdPesquisaCliente.item(self.grdPesquisaCliente.currentRow(), 0).text())
    self.close()
```

Then on ItemForm i just fixed method to don't close form after open dialog.

itemform.py

```
def search(self):
    item_search = ItemSearch(self)
    item_search.show()
```